# How to Fix Error Making JSON theme for Power BI

Tags: json, powerbi

I made a custom theme for Power BI but it's giving me an error and I can't find why. I used Microsoft's documentation on it but it seems very incomplete.

I'm basically trying to do the following at the bottom:

- vert grid = No with 1 thickness and white
- Horiz grid = No with 1 thickness and white
- Row padding = 10
- Outline = 1 thickness as white
- text size = 19
- column font = white with #234A6A background and is autosized using Arial 18 font

Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-report-themes#json-file-element-definitions

```
{

"name": "themeJ",

"textClasses": {
            "callout": {
                    "fontSize": 45,
                    "fontFace": "wf_standard-font",
                    "color": "#252423"
                },
            "title": {
                    "fontSize": 16,
                    "fontFace": "wf_standard-font",
                    "color": "#252423"
                },
            "header": {
                    "fontSize": 16,
                "fontFace": "Arial",
                "color": "#252423"
                },
            "label": {
                    "fontSize": 16,
                    "fontFace": "Arial",
                    "color": "#252423"
                }
            }    




"dataColors": [ 
    "#2F628D", 
    "#448DCA", 
    "#01B8AA", 
    "#F7B34C",
    "#FD625E",
    "#AEB5C1", 
    "#B19CD9", 
    "#7BA225"
     ],



"good": "#01B8AA",
"neutral": "#F7B34C",
"bad": "#FD625E",
"maximum": "#01B8AA",
"minimum": "#FD625E",
"background": "#FFFFFF",
"foreground": "#070f25",
"tableAccent":"#0F1934",
"visualStyles":{
    "tableEx":{
        "*":{
            "grid":[{
                "gridVertical":false,
                "gridVerticalColor":{
                    "solid":{
                        "color":"#ffffff"}},
                "gridVerticalWeight":1,
                "gridHorizontal":false,
                "gridHorizontalColor":{
                    "solid":{
                        "color":"#ffffff"}},
                "gridHorizontalWeight":1,
                "rowPadding":10,
                "outlineColor":{
                    "solid":{
                        "color":"#ffffff"}},
                "outlineWeight":1,
                "textSize":19}],
            "columnHeaders":[{
                "fontColor":{
                    "solid":{
                        "color":"#ffffff"}},
                "backColor":{
                    "solid":{
                        "color":"#234A6A"}},
                "autoSizeColumnWidth":true,
                "fontFamily":"Arial",
                "fontSize":18}]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Please update your question and include the error you're receiving.  Also, we need to see the relevant code segments that pertain to that error.

Comment: @devlincarnate it doesn't tell me where the errors are (i'm using notepad to write this, should I be using something else?)

All Power BI says is "There was a problem importing your theme file. Please try again or choose another file".

Answer (score 0):

From the supplied code it is not fully validated json, you are missing a ',' and you have extra '}' closing brackets.

```
{

"name": "themeJ",

"textClasses": {
            "callout": {
                    "fontSize": 45,
                    "fontFace": "wf_standard-font",
                    "color": "#252423"
                },
            "title": {
                    "fontSize": 16,
                    "fontFace": "wf_standard-font",
                    "color": "#252423"
                },
            "header": {
                    "fontSize": 16,
                "fontFace": "Arial",
                "color": "#252423"
                },
            "label": {
                    "fontSize": 16,
                    "fontFace": "Arial",
                    "color": "#252423"
                }
            },    




"dataColors": [ 
    "#2F628D", 
    "#448DCA", 
    "#01B8AA", 
    "#F7B34C",
    "#FD625E",
    "#AEB5C1", 
    "#B19CD9", 
    "#7BA225"
     ],



"good": "#01B8AA",
"neutral": "#F7B34C",
"bad": "#FD625E",
"maximum": "#01B8AA",
"minimum": "#FD625E",
"background": "#FFFFFF",
"foreground": "#070f25",
"tableAccent":"#0F1934",
"visualStyles":{
    "tableEx":{
        "*":{
            "grid":[{
                "gridVertical":false,
                "gridVerticalColor":{
                    "solid":{
                        "color":"#ffffff"}},
                "gridVerticalWeight":1,
                "gridHorizontal":false,
                "gridHorizontalColor":{
                    "solid":{
                        "color":"#ffffff"}},
                "gridHorizontalWeight":1,
                "rowPadding":10,
                "outlineColor":{
                    "solid":{
                        "color":"#ffffff"}},
                "outlineWeight":1,
                "textSize":19}],
            "columnHeaders":[{
                "fontColor":{
                    "solid":{
                        "color":"#ffffff"}},
                "backColor":{
                    "solid":{
                        "color":"#234A6A"}},
                "autoSizeColumnWidth":true,
                "fontFamily":"Arial",
                "fontSize":18}]
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This updated code import fin into Power BI.
I would also recommend that as a start you use a [Power BI Theme generator](https://powerbi.tips/tools/report-theme-generator-v3/) to start the outline of what you want.

I've created a basic output in the generator which looks like

```
{
   "name":"My Theme",
   "background":"#01B8AA",
   "foreground":"#01B8AA",
   "tableAccent":"#01B8AA",
   "dataColors":[
      "#2F628D",
      "#448DCA",
      "#01B8AA"
   ],
   "visualStyles":{
      "*":{
         "*":{
            "*":[
               {
                  "fontSize":16,
                  "fontFamily":"Arial",
                  "color":{
                     "solid":{

                     }
                  }
               }
            ]
         }
      },
      "tableEx":{
         "*":{
            "grid":[
               {
                  "gridVertical":false,
                  "gridVerticalColor":{
                     "solid":{
                        "color":"#01B8AA"
                     }
                  },
                  "gridVerticalWeight":1,
                  "gridHorizontal":false,
                  "gridHorizontalColor":{
                     "solid":{
                        "color":"#01B8AA"
                     }
                  },
                  "gridHorizontalWeight":1,
                  "rowPadding":10,
                  "outlineColor":{
                     "solid":{
                        "color":"#01B8AA"
                     }
                  },
                  "outlineWeight":1,
                  "textSize":19
               }
            ],
            "columnHeaders":[
               {
                  "fontColor":{
                     "solid":{
                        "color":"#01B8AA"
                     }
                  },
                  "backColor":{
                     "solid":{
                        "color":"#01B8AA"
                     }
                  },
                  "autoSizeColumnWidth":true,
                  "fontFamily":"Arial",
                  "fontSize":18
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Hope that helps point you in the right direction

Comment: Thank you for the help @Jonee, Unfortunately the code still doesn't work unless I take out both the visualStyles and the textClasses - any idea why?

Comment: As mentioned in the answer, use the report theme generator and start with the base settings of your colours then keep adding to the json to see where it breaks. I recreated most of your JSON in the theme creator, without an issue.